# concatenation php variable in the path of file upload

Tags: php, concatenation

```
$i = 3292;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['doc_path']['tmp_name'], '../../../../uploads/documents/'.$i.'/'.$photograph);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['doc_path']['tmp_name'], '../../../../uploads/documents/3292/'.$photograph);
```

What is the problem in the above code. concatenation is also correct but when i use $i static it works fine.Please help

Comment: **error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);** Any error if you put this in your script?

Answer (score 1):

Store path in one variable and use it.

```
$i = 3292;
$path = '../../../../uploads/documents/'.$i.'/'.$photograph;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['doc_path']['tmp_name'], $path);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['doc_path']['tmp_name'], '../../../../uploads/documents/3292/'.$photograph);
```